# Faster Rails single partial render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, haml, partial

I need to avoid an often repeat of the same code block into template.
Example:

```
%a{href:item_path(item.web_title,@relative_link_options)}
  =item.show_field_locale('title')
  -unless item.get_image_path('has_image',"item_#{item.id}.png").blank?
    =image_tag(item.get_image_path('has_image',"item_#{item.id}.png"))
```

So, I describe many items, **NOT** from collection @items. That are has-one relations or small has-many relations. 
I have a lot of such pages, so too many different content for caching.

To display every item I need to repeat an above code block.
Also I could use partial `_item.html.haml` and use it via `render partial: 'item'`
But it slows an application (time to prepare Views in ms).
How could I avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

For example, I'm solving such problem with https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/embed_view

but it requires to have ERB views